# How to omit \u2028 line separator in Python?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

I have a text file including non ASCII char and I want to read in the file line by line. But one of the lines is:

```
Hello\u2028world!
```

where the `\u2028` is the line separator.

---

The script for reading the file is:

```
# Python 2.7.10
import codecs
with codecs.open('path_to_file', 'r', encoding='utf8') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        // Process each line
```

The issue occurred when the statement `for line in fh` find the `\u2028` and treat it as end of line. As a result, the line was split into two lines.

How could I skip or replace the `\u2028` and keep the line in a single line?

Comment: What Python version are you using? When it comes to unicode processing, Python2 and 3 can behave differently.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Python 2.7, I forgot to add the version in comment. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
file_contents = fh.read().replace('\u2028',' ').splitlines()
```

This will read the file, replace all instances of `\u2028` with a space, and split the resulting string into lines (so `file_contents` will be a list). So your code would look like this:

```
import codecs
with codecs.open('path_to_file', 'r', encoding='utf8') as fh:
    file_contents = fh.read().replace('\u2028',' ').splitlines()
    for line in file_contents:
        ## Process each line
```

Answer (score 1):

The character `u'\u2028'` is indeed declared as a line separator ([SEP L](http://www.unicode.org/fr/charts/PDF/U2000.pdf)) in unicode. That could explain why the codecs module uses it as an end of line.

In your case, the problem comes from the `codecs.open`. In fact, I think that this method should never be used. The documentation states:

> Note : 
>   Files are always opened in binary mode, even if no binary mode was specified. This is done to avoid data loss due to encodings using 8-bit values. This means that no automatic conversion of '\n' is done on reading and writing.

what would cause problems on Windows system.

So my advice is to keep away from `codecs.open` and process in two distinct phases, first io access and then unicode convertion:

```
with open('hw.txt', 'rt') as fd:
    for rawline in fd:
        line = rawline.decode('utf8')
        # process line
```

BTW, I also tested that with Python3.4. This code works correctly:

```
with open('hw.txt', 'rt', encoding='utf8') as fd:
    for line in fd:
        print ('>', repr(line))
```

and shows the include `u'\2028'` in first line (Python 3 directly gives unicode strings), whereas using `codecs.open` also splits on `u'2028'` and lives `\r\n` as end of line on Windows.

TL/DR: except for very special use cases, keep away from `codecs.open`!

Comment: Ironically, I had one of these special cases, and this answer helped me realize that I _did_ want to use `codecs.open`. (The special case is reading from a text file created from a copied/pasted `Notes.app` document, FWIW; apparently `Notes.app` inserts `\u2028` when you hit enter.)